# Editing HTML then posting via PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, security, developer-tools

I have a scenario. Let's say someone is on my website and there is a form which adds an event for example and there is a field as follows:

```
<input type="text" name="title" id="title">
```

Let's say that person used F12 developer tools and changes the id="title" to id="whatever", or even remove the id attribute, then how would I make my PHP script stop running so that nothing is posted to MySQL?

Here's an example for a Bookmarks feature I have: (front-end form)

```
<form action="bookmarks.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="input-mini">Title*</label>
    <div class="controls">
       <input class="span12" id="title" name="title" type="text" placeholder="e.g. Oliver's pet cat...">
    </div>
  </div><!-- /control-group -->
  <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="input-mini">Link*</label>
    <div class="controls">
       <input class="span12" id="link" name="link" type="text" placeholder="e.g. http://boopeo.com">
       <input type="hidden" name="parse_var" id="parse_var" value="addbookmark" />
       <br /><input name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-success span12" value="Bookmark" /></form>
```

Back-end PHP:

```
if (isset($_POST['parse_var'])){
             $parser = $_POST['parse_var'];
             $parser = htmlspecialchars($parser);
    if ($parser == "addbookmark"){


             $title = $_POST['title'];
             $title = htmlspecialchars($title);
             $linkurl = $_POST['link'];
             $linkurl = htmlspecialchars($linkurl);

    $sqlrecentmark = $db->query("SELECT link_url FROM tablenamehere WHERE mem_id='$id' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 20");
    while($row = $sqlrecentmark->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
      $recent_link = $row["link_url"]; 
    }

    if ( $linkurl != $recent_link ){
         $dataact = array( 'mem_id' => $id, 'title' => $title, 'link_url' => $linkurl );  

    $sqlactivity = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO tablenamehere (mem_id, title, link_url) value (:mem_id, :title, :link_url)");  
    $sqlactivity->execute($dataact);
    } else {
        $not_msg = '<br /><br /><div class="alert alert-error">Oops! You have added that bookmark before. Just look and you shall find!</div>';
    }
    }
    }
```

Comment: never trust user submitted data, always validate and sanitize... and don't forget you must use parametrized query

Comment: can you post your front-end form and back-end php code? this looks more like an issue related to back-end input sanitization. Not sure if this scenario is exactly harmful but it looks interesting.

Comment: I'll use a different example for the front form:

Comment: I'll post the example in the question now

Comment: since you are using prepared statements in the back-end, you should mostly be good on the MySQL security part. For additional security measures, you might want to validate and sanitize your input. Look at GUMP php library. That might be helpful here: https://github.com/Wixel/GUMP

Comment: use prepared statements for $sqlrecentmark query too.

Comment: Thanks I will :) But if a user was to remove the id="title" attribute from the HTML then run the PHP script by submitting the form, it posts the other existing values then returns an error (Notice: Undefined index: title in /home/jdowen/public_html/lb/edge/tools/bookmarks.php on line 22) which reveals file paths, etc. How do I stop this as this is a security risk?

Comment: The validation/sanitization logic should take care of that part. That is why that should be the first thing that you should do on your back-end PHP page. In most simple terms you can do something like if (isset($_POST['title'])){} on your PHP page.

Answer (score 1):

Never trust data from the user. Always sanitize and validate. You are using prepared statements which is good, so you'll be mostly protected from injection. The other thing you'll want to do is determine if the data the user has sent you matches up with what you were expecting, if it does then proceed to use it with the database. (Which you are for the most part doing, so in all honesty there should be no bad effects from a malicious user)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, a real help :) But if a user was to remove the id="title" attribute from the HTML then run the PHP script by submitting the form, it posts the other existing values then returns an error (Notice: Undefined index: title in /home/jdowen/public_html/lb/edge/tools/bookmarks.php on line 22) which reveals file paths, etc. How do I stop this as this is a security risk?

Comment: Two things, one is that in production code you shouldn't be showing errors to the user (you can change the settings in your php.ini file) and are you checking isset before you use it?

Answer (score 1):

The `id` of input field doesn't get passed as posted data, so there's no way to tell in the back-end php code. Maybe you're talking about the `name` attribute.

```
<input type="text" name="theTitle" id="aTitle">
```

In my above example, the input field will be posted as `$_POST["theTitle"]`

You could use javascript to check these elements before the form is submitted, but if you're worried about the user manipulating the DOM, that probably won't help much.

After reading your concern about the Undefined index error, you simply need to check if the variable is set before you use it:

```
if(isset($_POST["title"])) {
  $title = $_POST['title'];
} else {
  //output error
}
```